# Why are there redundant ways to import in Python?

Tags: python, python-import

Unless I'm mistaken, these two lines do exactly the same thing:

```
import theano.tensor as T

from theano import tensor as T
```

Is there any reason why there are redundant ways to import in Python?

Comment: That may explain how the situation came to be, but then the question would be why was one chosen to be a standard over the other?

Comment: They don't do the same thing *in all circumstances*...

Answer (score 6):

The statement

```
import theano.tensor
```

only works if `theano.tensor` is a *module* itself. This is what permits both your examples to work.

Consider `sys.argv`, which is not a module. The following works:

```
from sys import argv
```

which imports `argv` into the global namespace, but the `import` form does not:

```
>>> import sys.argv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named argv
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks. And for a noob followup, what technically is the name for `sys.argv` if it is not a module?

Comment: So you are saying that we can use the  dot notation just to access submodules, otherwise we cannot use this notation..?

Comment: `sys.argv` is just the fully qualified name of an object (in this case, an instance of `list`.)

Comment: and `sys` is not a module, and instead is a ___?

Comment: @MattO'Brien: `sys` certainly is a module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html. Most of the things available in modules are just regular objects, but sometimes there are other modules contained inside modules. For example, the [`os` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) contains the `os.path` module. In your case, the `theano` module contains a module called `tensor`.